# Discord Py emoji

Tags: python, discord

Hi I want that my Discord Bot can send custom emojis. But he only sends ":4h:"

```
@client.command(name="customemoji")
async def customemoji(ctx):
  await ctx.send("<:4H:833409515504009217>")
```

Comment: Maybe try to use this: instead of 4H:... https://discord.com/assets/c4a0dcc8ff99eb77285d772b6b577389.svg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was it was just the wrong ID.

Comment: For future reference, your bot must be in the server from which you want to use an emoji from.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Guild.emojis`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20emoji#discord.Guild.emojis) to get a list of `discord.Emoji` objects. You could then use `discord.utils.get()` to get the appropriate emoji based on the ID, then send that emoji object.

```py
@client.command(name="customemoji")
async def customemoji(ctx):
    emoji = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.emojis, id=833409515504009217)
    await ctx.channel.send(emoji)
```

Comment: I get then an error:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message

Answer (score 0):

There is a website getemoji.com from where you can copy all the emotes and paste them into your discord name or channel.
This has been explained on my own blog [how to add an emoji to the discord channel](https://discordtips.com/how-to-add-emojis-to-discord-channels/).

If you want to add a few stream trending emotes like MonkaW.
You can visit the BetterTTV website and click on emotes.
Here you will see all the emojis, right-click on the one that you want and then click on Save image.

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.